# delete an object from an array of objects in local storage javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have an array of objects in local storage like this:

```
ios = [{
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "in",
    "cat" : "Diversi",
    "qty" : 50,
    "date" : "2016-11-02T09:51:48.872Z",
    "descr" : ""
  }, {
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "in",
    "cat" : "Lavoro",
    "qty" : 50,
    "date" : "2016-11-02T10:08:11.362Z",
    "descr" : ""
  }];
```

I want to delete one of the objects with this function:

```
function remove(io) {
    var ios = localStorage.getItem('ios') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ios')) : [];
    var index;
    for (var i = 0; i < ios.length; i++) {
        if (ios[i] === io) {
          index=i;
          break;
        }
    }
    ios.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('ios', JSON.stringify(ios));
}
```

But when i call the function, and pass it the parameter to delete, it doesn't delete the one I want, but the first one in local storage instead.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: try replacing `if (ios[i] === io) {` with `if (JSON.stringify(ios[i]) === JSON.stringify(io)) {`

Comment: what gets passed to `remove`? Is it an object?

Comment: @OliverRadini yes i pass an object

Comment: Don't splice, filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your condition never get satisfied, so your **index** variable is always **undefined** ... So either pass some unique key value in the object like "id" and compare that key value pair like :-

```
function remove(id) {
    var ios = localStorage.getItem('ios') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ios')) : [];
    var index;
    for (var i = 0; i < ios.length; i++) {
        if (ios[i].id === id) {
          index=i;
          break;
        }
    }
    if(index === undefined) return 
    ios.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('ios', JSON.stringify(ios));
}
```

**OR**

use some third party like LODASH [Doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#findIndex) as:-

```
function remove(io) {
        var ios = localStorage.getItem('ios') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ios')) : [];
        var index;
        index = _.findIndex(ios , io);
        if(index === -1) return 
        ios.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('ios', JSON.stringify(ios));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't test 2 objects being equal by using `===`. Try to use this function:

```
function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = aProps[i];

        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And instead `ios[i] === io`, you call `isEquivalent(ios[i],io)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function as,

```
function removeItem() {    
  var ios = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ios'));
  var index = ios.map(function(element) {
    return element.cat;
  }).indexOf(io.cat);
  ios.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('ios', JSON.stringify(ios));
}
```

to remove item based on passed object's cat in the array. [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/as8wo78L/)